# How to allow DNS lookup with iptables on Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, dns, iptables

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Server and trying to make a router.
When I execute the following iptables script (which worked just perfectly on Ubuntu 16.04), the DNS lookup from command line stops working. I have ping to IP addresses, but no DNS names.
Something is obviously changed from 16.04, but don't know what.

**EDIT: I started executing lines one by one and defined the culprit is this:**

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

**But still don't know why** (it worked on previous Ubuntu versions - 16.04, 14.04, 12.04)

The ping output is:

```
# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

If I reboot WITHOUT this script, it works:

```
# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.169.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from sof02s32-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.169.142): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=2.92 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll answer my own question.
The cure was to add an external interface in the iptables line, so it now looks like this:

```
ExtIF=eno1 ##Change this to the name of your external (Internet) interface    
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o $ExtIF -j MASQUERADE
```

Maybe some iptables guru would be able to answer in the comments why the DNS lookup is failing only from localhost, only in Ubuntu 18.04.